# How to get numeric value from cURL array?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I'm trying to fetch numeric value from the cURL response array. But Unable to do that. I'm Using this code

```
     $urltopost = "http://www.xxxx.yyy.com/zzz.php";
     $ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
     print_r($returndata);
```

Its prints this **Our new Invoice ID is: [{-10191}]** on the page. Now I want to fetch 10191 from the array. I tried this one but failed.

```
     $id = abs(filter_var(implode($returndata), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```

How can i retreive the numeric value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You got the `$returndata` is like **string**

---

**Put this after curl_exec:**

```
<?php

$urltopost = "http://www.xxxx.yyy.com/zzz.php";
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
//$returndata = 'Our new Invoice (ID) is: [{-10191}]';
preg_match_all("/\{([^\]]*)\}/", $returndata, $matches);
$invoiceID = intval(ltrim($matches[1][0], '-'));
print_r($invoiceID);
```

Comment: Yes the data is like string. But it didn't work in my case. I need the numeric value for further use but i couldn't get it out.

Comment: What type of variable you want? it gives you int value. @buddy